# What is the better way to change/check values?

Tags: java

I was wondering what the best way to change/check values. For instance, if I have the following code:

```
public class Test{
    private int test1;

    public void checkValue(){
        setTest1(10);
        if(getTest1() <= 20){
            setTest1(30);
        }
    }
    public void setTest1(int test1){
    this.test1 = test1;
    }
    public int getTest1(){
    return test1;
    }
}
```

is this better where you use getter and setter? Or is this better:

```
public class Test(){
    private int test1 = 10;
    public void checkValue(){
    if(test1 <= 20){
    test1 = 10;
    }
}
```

where you use the raw values?

Comment: `public class Test()` wrong syntax. Please edit.

Comment: Your question like we should use GETTER/SETTER OR directly FIELD. It depends. If you do some kind of Validation ( In Setters ) OR Conversion ( In setters/getters ) you should use Getter/setter here. If you do nothing except value set/value return, in other instance methods, you can use DIRECTLY field. In your case, you can use second method.

Comment: I'm always of the opinion that if the object will be used in a variety of locations in the code, the fields should always either be protected or private and only accessed through getters/setters.  It prevents accidental settings and refactoring can be done entirely in the class later, instead of hunting down accesses.

Comment: Agree with @ddaviddkim Use getters and setters.  The vast majority of your getters and setters will be trivial implementations, but there will be occasions where you will be happy to have them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense to use the getters and setters from within the same class. The main purpose of getters and setters is to provide extensibility and a stable interface, however inside the class itself there is no need to rely on the external interface in order to change some internal field.

So I vote for this (the if is redundant, field should be private):

```
public class Test{
    private int test1;

    public void changeValue(){
        test1 = 30;
    }
    public void setTest1(int test1){
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
    public int getTest1(){
        return test1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case where the class has no invariants, then I would suggest dealing with private fields directly in methods as the code is cleaner.

But if you do have invariants, i.e. the values of some fields constrain what values other fields may or may not have, then it might be best to use setters to ensure that the invariants are maintained.

Simple example where boolean prime is true when value is a prime number:

```
class Test {
    private boolean isPrime;
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value) {
      this.isPrime = isNumberPrime(value);
      this.value = value;
    }

    public void addOneWithSetter() {
       setValue(getValue()+1); //doing it this way means we don't forget to calculate
                               //isPrime, so invariance is maintained
    }

    public void addOneWithoutSetter() {
       value = value+1;   //oops! forgot to set isPrime, so now invariance is broken
    }

    //getters...
}
```

Either way, I would not recommend making fields public, so in the code above, test1 should be

```
private int test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My teacher told me he would kill me if my values(I mean fields) are not private.
Only use setter if you really need it. If you want to access a value from an other class use getters. 
And your constructor is wrong remove "class".

Comment: public class Test() { ...} isn't your constructor ?